# expected an indented block on try

Tags: python, sqlite, error-handling

i'm a new python learner. i have created an program and i connect with sqlite db. but when i run the program is showing expected an indented block error. how can i find out the error and how can i fix it? looking for your help please... my code sample as follow.

```
def Book():
try:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} ({vn}, {vm}, {vma}, {vnos}) VALUES (VehicleNo.get(), VehicleModel.get(), VehicleMake.get(), NoofSeat.get())".\
        format(tn="Vehicle", vn="vnumver", vm="vmodel", vma="vmade", vnos="vnumofseat"))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print('ERROR: ID already exists in PRIMARY KEY column {}')


c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {tn} ({vn}, {vm}, {vma}, {vnos})) VALUES (VehicleNo.get(), VehicleModel.get(), VehicleMake.get(), NoofSeat.get())".\
        format(tn="Vehicle", vn="vnumver", vm="vmodel", vma="vmade", vnos="vnumofseat"))

#Driver
try:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} ({dn}, {dl}, {dp}) VALUES (DriverName.get(), LicenseNo.get(), Phone.get())".\
        format(tn="Driver", dn="dname", dl="dlicence", dp="dphone"))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print('ERROR: ID already exists in PRIMARY KEY column {}')


c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {tn} ({dn}, {dl}, {dp})) VALUES (DriverName.get(), LicenseNo.get(), Phone.get())".\
        format(tn="Driver", dn="dname", dl="dlicence", dp="dphone"))

#Customer
try:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO {tn} ({cname}, {cadd}, {cphone}, {cfrom}, {cto}, {chire}, {cdate}, {crate}, {ctotalm}, {ctotalcost}) VALUES (DriverName.get(), LicenseNo.get(), Phone.get())".\
        format(tn="Customer", cname="cname", cadd="caddress", cphone="cphone", cfrom="cfrom", cto="cto", chire="chire", cdate="cdate", crate="crate", ctotalm="ctotalm", ctotalcost="ctotalcost"))
except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
    print('ERROR: ID already exists in PRIMARY KEY column {}')


c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {tn} ({cname}, {cadd}, {cphone}, {cfrom}, {cto}, {chire}, {cdate}, {crate}, {ctotalm}, {ctotalcost})) VALUES (CustomerName.get(), Address.get(), Phone.get(), )".\
        format(tn="Customer", cname="cname", cadd="caddress", cphone="cphone", cfrom="cfrom", cto="cto", chire="chire", cdate="cdate", crate="crate", ctotalm="ctotalm", ctotalcost="ctotalcost"))
```

Comment: Basic rule: if a line ends on `:` the next line has to be indented more. Best practice is 4 spaces more.

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent the code in a function (the 2nd line is one of the places you didn't do this), here is an example:

```
def newFunction(x):
     if (x < 5):
          x = 2
```

Python is more sensitive to how you arrange the code so you should watch out for this if you are used to JS, HTML, etc.